# Updated RealmResults with time-based query

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

I'm starting to approach this wonderful world of Realm. I'm very happy of the results I'm getting and now I have one question to submit.

In my android app I've got a Fragment that displays data retrieved from Realm. The query condition is that the time this data refers to is in between the beginning and the end of today.

```
RealmResults<Appointment> results = realm
    .where(MyObject.class)
    .between("begin", rangeBegin, rangeEnd)
    .between("end", rangeBegin, rangeEnd)
    .findAllSorted("begin", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

This query is executed in the onStart() method helping me to exploit the live-update feature, which indeed works very well.
I've also added listeners for changes in order to optimize UI updates.

Now the question is: how does this live-update behave if the time conditions change? (Imagine I keep the app opened for more than one day without touching it or simply I keep the app opened for minutes around midnight)

From what I've seen it seems to do the same query done the very first time onStart() was executed.

Is there a way to have also live-updating query or should I re-run that query somewhere else outside onStart()?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the question is: how does this live-update behave if the time conditions change? (Imagine I keep the app opened for more than one day without touching it or simply I keep the app opened for minutes around midnight)

The query is pretty constant after you've set it up, so you'd need to execute a new query with different parameters for `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd`, and replace your other results.

> This query is executed in the onStart() method helping me to exploit the live-update feature, which indeed works very well. I've also added listeners for changes in order to optimize UI updates.

Personally I'd advise to put the query in `onCreateView()` instead, and the Realm lifecycle management to `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`.

Also, you can avoid manually assigning RealmChangeListeners for displaying lists if you use [RealmRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) (adapters 1.3.0 works with realm 1.2.0).

If you use `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, then just call `adapter.updateData(newResults);` and it'll update the view as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use RealmRecyclerViewAdapter later in another Fragment, here I don't need it. Why do you suggest onCreateView()? I've followed the tutorial here https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Comment: I [trust it more than onStart/onStop](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3362#issuecomment-243145655), that's all :)

Comment: If I do execute a new query, the listeners will be triggered for changes on the result of the new query, right?

Comment: If you add the results of the new query to the realm adapter with `adapter.updateData(newResults)`, then yes